# Calculate actual distance between two points using Google Directions API

Tags: objective-c, mapkit

In my iphone application i am creating a route between two points and using the google directions api to show the html instructions, step distance for each turn in text format.

When using the Directions API i had observed that when the user moves from location A to location D and there is a turn at location B, then the user is notified regarding the turn (i.e in the step of the json response from the direction api ) at point A' (consider A' between A and B). Now the distance of this step should be till location B, but i had found that it is till location B' (which appears after B), now again if i have a turn at location C
then the start location of step should start from location B, instead it starts from B'.

So my question is how would the user know the actual length of the step. Kindly help.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This doesn't really answer your question, but I thought I should mention it anyway.

Once iOS 6 rolls out in a few months, you won't be able to use Google's services to do this. Not for any technical reason, but in their TOS, they explicitly state that if you use their mapping services, they must be used in conjunction with their maps. Since Apple is using a different map provider come iOS 6, you would be in violation of their terms.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. But while creating this app we are going to target the older ios versions too.                              Hence is there any way to find the accurate length of the step, or do i need to consider the same value which the google directions api response displays?

Answer (score 0):

I had solved the issue related to calculate the actual length of the step.
Actually i was simulating the current location by taking fake locations and testing it.
In live mode (i.e while testing the application on the road) it works perfectly fine.